# Same value for all rows and total in PowerBi

Tags: powerbi

I would like to present movie count for movie director. PowerBI is showing the same result for each row and total as well. I checked relationship, and looks ok. Any idea how to solve it?

I checked relationship, and looks ok. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Normally, that's an indication of a missing relationship, but since we can't see your tables or relationships, we can't tell.